# adding a paramater to all website URLS. But exclude files

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following function to add `refcode` url paramater to all wordpress URLS.

I've noticed that it is also adding to the CSS files and JS files being called on the website, which is causing issues loading certain external stylesheets

```
function wprdcv_param_redirect(){

$referalpin = $_GET['refpin'];
if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
if (!$referalpin){
    global $wpdb;
$ioppin = bp_get_profile_field_data('field=211&user_id='.bp_loggedin_user_id());




    $location = add_query_arg(array('refpin' => $ioppin,));
    wp_redirect($location);
}
}
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wprdcv_param_redirect');
```

Is there anything i could add to just purely make it front facing URLS that it adds the paramater to, instead of all urls to do with wordpress?

Comment: What keeps you from checking the URL before modifying it?

Comment: On a side note, please don't be one of _those_ developers. Always format/indent your code properly...for the respect of the people helping you here, if not for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the URL before performing a redirect:

```
function wprdcv_param_redirect()
{
    $referalpin = $_GET['refpin'] ?? '';

    if (is_user_logged_in() && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.js') === false && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.css') === false) {
        $ioppin = bp_get_profile_field_data('field=211&user_id=' . bp_loggedin_user_id());

        if (!$referalpin) {
            $location = add_query_arg(array('refpin' => $ioppin));
            wp_redirect($location);
        }
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wprdcv_param_redirect');
```